# askWithCarousel() is returning empty response

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, api-ai, dialogflow-es

here is the code snippet i'm using:

```
app.askWithCarousel('Which of these looks good?',
    app.buildCarousel()
        .addItems([
            app.buildOptionItem("SELECTION_KEY_ONE",
                ['synonym of KEY_ONE 1', 'synonym of KEY_ONE 2'])
                .setTitle('Number one'),
            app.buildOptionItem("SELECTION_KEY_TWO",
                ['synonym of KEY_TWO 1', 'synonym of KEY_TWO 2'])
                .setTitle('Number two'),
        ]));
```

here is the screenshot:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you update the simulator screen shot to show the results from where it says "isn't responding right now"? You're showing the debug from when it says it isn't available in simulation, which is the error after the conversation has closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. It's probably a Google bug. All you have to do is to add `.setDescription` method

```
app.askWithCarousel('Which of these looks good?',
    app.buildCarousel()
        .addItems(
            app.buildOptionItem("SELECTION_KEY_ONE",
                            ['synonym of KEY_ONE 1', 'synonym of KEY_ONE 2'])
                            .setTitle('Number one')
                            .setDescription('Number one description')
            )
        .addItems(
            app.buildOptionItem("SELECTION_KEY_TWO",
                            ['synonym of KEY_TWO 1', 'synonym of KEY_TWO 2'])
                            .setTitle('Number two')
                            .setDescription('Number two description')
            )
);
```

---

**UPDATE**

I've found out just now it's impossible to set an empty string like `.setDescription('')`. It returns an error. So, I got along with space `.setDescription(' ')`